# how to show gridline in the column header after applying background

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid

After applying background to column header, the grid line cannot be seen anymore. Any simple way to get the gridline back?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify BorderBrush and BorderThickness for the DataGridColumnHeader. Example

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```